# No output from my Java code

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, javax.comm

I want to find the ports present in the Windows 7 and I have written code for it. It successfully compiles but there is no output. I have Compiled in Netbeans

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;  
import javax.comm.*;

public class PortLister {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Enumeration e = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();  
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {  
            System.out.println((CommPortIdentifier) e.nextElement());  
        } 
    }  
}
```

Comment: I think No elements in Enumeration :)

Comment: Did you try to debug this application and inspect `e`?

Comment: Are you getting an exception?

Comment: Did you see these articles? http://www.coderanch.com/t/535173/Streams/java/CommPortIdentifier-getPortIdentifiers-empty and http://pradnyanaik.wordpress.com/2009/04/07/communicating-with-ports-using-javaxcomm-package-for-windows/

Comment: It seems no elements in the e . Can any one help me how to add ports Identifiers to the Enumeration.

Comment: Iam not getting any Sort of exceptions